# What is the intuition behind exponentials in the frequency domain signifying delay in a signal?

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Question is in the title.

I am trying to teach myself control theory and it involves a lot of taking things as truth without much intuition or proof. In particular, I'm trying to understand how $e^{s \tau}$ represents some form of delay.

For context when you answer, please consider that I am only familiar with Laplace transforms as a technique to algebraically solve differential equations in a very abstract context.

Thank you

Comment: Have you seen the delay rule in Laplace transforms? Compare with these questions. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971377/laplace-transform-of-a-ramp-function-with-a-2-second-delay), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898174/laplace-transform-and-delay) for just some information.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza Thank you, #1 answered my question, at least from the standpoint of proving that applying the definition of the transform to a function with a delay results in the exponential.

Comment: Great! If that answered your question completely then I suggest we close this as a duplicate. If not, maybe edit the question.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza I wouldn't call it a duplicate. I was looking for intuition, but discovered that none exists in the geometric sense I was asking for. The only reasoning available is through direct application of the definition of the Laplace transform. 

I'm okay with closing it, but wanted to caveat the closure.